# Should I use AMQP RPC or AMQP + REST

Tags: rest, rabbitmq, rpc, amqp

I really like the idea of setting up a service such as RabbitMQ to handle my larger jobs and have n workers scale and process those requests. My question lies in if I should also handle 'quick' actions a user performs in the UI, such as saving small changes in a form, through the queue.

When I read about AMQP RPC it sounds like this would WORK for this kind of task, but is it the smart thing to do for such a use case? Am I making it more complicated than it should be and should use REST + AMQP depending on task?

Comment: look on my answer on other question http://stackoverflow.com/a/17296885/1461984, maybe it will help you to decide

Comment: please, specify target platform (language) you are planing to use

Answer (score 0):

There's another alternative for message queueing which is more lightweight than AMQP (RabbitMQ) because of brokerless architecture - ZeroMQ. It works with IPC in mind so you can easily use it for interaction of UI and Controller. Performance issues must be investigated further though.