# HTTP/REST and AMQP

Tags: http, amqp

What is the difference between synchronous and asynchronous protocols?
Why http/rest is synchronous while AMQP is asynchronous?
Where can I have a good overview on these two protocols?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Service Oriented Architecture - AMQP or HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838416/service-oriented-architecture-amqp-or-http)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a interesting description of AMQP in wikipedia.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol

There is a interesting description abot sync / async on Stackoverflow.

[Asynchronous vs synchronous execution, what does it really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean)